# Non-functional sleep, switch directly to the login screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend

[Solved - installing another version of driver (470) solved this problem for me]

I've problem with sleep after installing NVidia proprietary driver (460).

When i sleep my PC, the login screen will appear immediately (it looks like this is a problem with X11).
Logs from KSystemLog are here:

https://pasteboard.co/KfikrO1.png

https://pasteboard.co/Kfikyxf.png

https://pasteboard.co/KfikEqnW.png

My system is KDE NEON with all updates.

(I don't want to reinstall the graphics drivers, because I had enough problems with them and I'm glad they work now.)

Does anyone have an idea for solution?

Thanks a lot, sorry for my bad english and have a nice day!

Comment: What's your swap configuration? ```free -h``` Maybe your system is trying to hibernate instead and it does not have enough swap.

Comment: I have 2 GB swap - 2 GB free. This problem I started having after installing Nvidia driver, I think. When I had nouveau driver, suspend is worked.

Comment: I solved this problem installing nvidia driver in version 470. Now sleep is work!